Trying to use tkinterdnd but I can't load tkinter library in Python
I want to drag and drop items onto the gui. I believe thats possible with tkinter? But whenever I try to run this, I get this error:
File "/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/RegExorcist/regexorcist.py", line 92, in <module>
    window = TkinterDnD.Tk()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tkinterdnd2/TkinterDnD.py", line 285, in __init__
    self.TkdndVersion = _require(self)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tkinterdnd2/TkinterDnD.py", line 55, in _require
    raise RuntimeError('Unable to load tkdnd library.')
RuntimeError: Unable to load tkdnd library.

This is what I added to my code:
from tkinterdnd2 import TkinterDnD, DND_FILES

# GUI
window = TkinterDnD.Tk()
window.title('RegExorcist')

# Bind drag-and-drop events
window.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
window.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', on_drop)
window.dnd_bind('<<DragEnter>>', on_drag_enter)


I have installed tkinter, tkinterdnd, tkinterdnd2
How can I make the code work and remove the error?

Extra information:
I'm on VC Code. I have Python 3.12.3 /opt/homebrew/bin/python3, Python 3.12.3 /usr/local/bin/python3 and one Python 3.9.6 /usr/bin/python3. I use the first one for it. When I use the second one, tkinterdnd becomes yellow.

I always refrain to use Stackoverflow because of this very reason. On Reddit I can just create a post in 2 minutes without being scared of losing progress scared because the dumb AI of this site wont accept the post. Am I the only one that is experiencing this?

Are you running your project in a virtual environment by any chance? Or perhaps you have more than one Python interpreter installed (which is pretty common on Mac)

I'm on VC Code. I have Python 3.12.3 /opt/homebrew/bin/python3, Python 3.12.3 /usr/local/bin/python3 and one Python 3.9.6 /usr/bin/python3. I use the first one for it. When I use the second one, tkinterdnd becomes yellow.

Special thanks to TheLizzard for removing my rant about this platform. I dont mind really, at least I was able to post this.

Try installing tkinterdnd2-universal instead of tkinterdnd2.

Thanks @acw1668 someone beat you to it on Reddit but for anyone that has this issue, this is it.

I installed tkinterdnd2-universal instead of tkinterdnd2 and that fixed the issue.
